# JavaFX hyperlink in selected table cell CSS

Tags: javafx

When a hyperlink control is placed in a table cell, and the cell/row is selected, the default blue cell selection color interferes with the hyperlink's light blue text color to make the hyperlink text virtually unreadable.

Normal text in such a table cell changes color from its default black into white in this scenario, but the hyperlink text does not.

What is the correct CSS to apply to .hyperlink in order to change its text color when in a selected table cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
.table-cell .hyperlink {
    -fx-text-fill: ladder(-fx-background, -fx-light-text-color 50%, -fx-accent 51% );
}
```

Another option is

```
.table-row-cell:selected .table-cell .hyperlink {
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-text-background-color ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```css
.table-row-cell:selected .hyperlink {
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}

.table-row-cell:selected .hyperlink:visited {
    -fx-text-fill: yellow;
}
```

this way you can also distinguish visited and unvisited links.